# Java,cloning classes with access restrictions

Tags: java, clone, encapsulation

I have :

- class Personne implements Cloneable...

The personne class uses Adress class in it's field.

- private Adresse adresse=ADRESSE_UNKNOWN;

So what i want is having a option to :

- modify the cloned Person adress

  Here is my clone method :

  ```
  Object o = null;
  try {
  o = super.clone();
  } catch(CloneNotSupportedException cnse) {
    cnse.printStackTrace(System.err);
      }
      return o;
  }
  ```
- BUT that the original Person class won t have the access to the
  Cloned Person class Adress field.

Please give me a tip.

Comment: Maybe cloning people is ethically wrong?

Comment: My tip would be to [avoid using `Cloneable`](http://www.artima.com/intv/bloch13.html)

Comment: Let s supose we r cloning in England where it is authorised

Comment: Why not override the clone() method and just modify address there when the clone() is called...

Comment: I will add it in the main topic ,cause here it puuting all in same line

Comment: ok here it is ,so what u mean by overriding the cloning ?

Comment: u mean changing the encapsulation level ? like to private ?

Comment: @Vladimir I just posted an example of a clone() method you could use that returns a clone of the object but changes the address of the returned clone while it leaves everything else the same...

Comment: thanks a lot ,that s cool but still not a solution ,almost but still ramains that access issue from original Persone class and the cloned one.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok Guys , so with help i understood. 
The possibility to override a clone() method is giving the opurtunity to modify the fields of the cloning class. As a proposed solution a reset the Adress field of the class to NULL.
Then i created a setter that giving an option to modify the clone adress field.

```
    @Override
    public Personne clone()
{
    Personne o;
    try {
       o = (Personne)super.clone();
       o.adresse = null;
       return o;
    } catch(CloneNotSupportedException cnse) {
      cnse.printStackTrace(System.err);
      throw new RuntimeException();
    }
}
 // setter pour l adresse du Clone :
    public void setAdresseClone(Adresse a){
    this.clone().adresse = a;
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
public Personne clone()
{
    Personne o;
    try {
       o = (Personne)super.clone();
       o.adresse = null;//or just change it however you want here.
       return o;
    } catch(CloneNotSupportedException cnse) {
      cnse.printStackTrace(System.err);
      throw new RuntimeException();
    }
}
```

Make sure the attributes of Personne are immutable if they are not you should call the clone() method for each attribute that is not immutable separately in the main clone() mehtod.

Comment: Ok ,looks good. But tell me : how u changing the access for Adress ?

Comment: @Vladimir I'm not changing the access for address it is still private but since the `clone()` method is also inside the `Personne` class it has access to the private attribute `adresse`.

Comment: yes it does ! that s exatly my problem. But looking at your code i say you are accessing to the adress field of the person and overriding it. But since it is modified it still could be accessed by the original Person class or not ?,if u see what i mean.

Comment: U think it may be a solution if i do this ?

Comment: p.s i l post in the main topic

Comment: @Vladimir The adresse is still private I am not changing the access modifier for adresse.  I am not sure what you are asking or why...maybe give an example of what you mean so I can understand.

Comment: @Vladimir what are you trying to accomplish. Create a copy of a `Personne` with everything the same except a different address?  Because if you are this is the correct solution.  adresse will still be private.

Comment: So i need to clone those bastards. And what i want is to have the possibility to modify the adress of the cloned one and keep the original person adress untouched.

Comment: @Vladimir yes this is exactly what I thought and this **IS** the correct solution.  Modifying original address will not modify copied address and vice versa.  Did you try this?  I even said if the objects are immutable you don't have to do anything else if they are immutable you should call clone() on each mutable object itself...

Comment: @Vladimir you should do your modifiying in the clone() method because after it's been cloned if you don't have setters you won't be able to modify adresse because it is private...

Comment: @Vladimir if you want to modify the adresse keep the field private but create a setter method in `Personne`

Comment: I see ... so i go with that clone method setting up the adress field to null ; and put a setter to have the option to modify the cloned one adress ,right ?

Comment: ok i understand now ! The problem i didn t thought that u got that possibility to Override any fields in clone() methods.

Comment: @Vladimir yes that would be one solution.

Comment: thats make sense now.

Comment: @Vladimir awesome man I hope I was able to help you out even though it took a while lol